# Spark scala dynamically create filter condition value from sequence Pair

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a spark dataframe : df :

```
|id | year | month |
-------------------
| 1 | 2020 | 01    |
| 2 | 2019 | 03    |
| 3 | 2020 | 01    |
```

I have a sequence `year_month = Seq[(2019,01),(2020,01),(2021,01)]`

val year_map gets genrated dynamically based on code runs everytime

I want to filter the dataframe : df  based on the year_month sequence for on ($year=seq[0] & $month = seq[1]) for each value pair in sequence year_month

Comment: you may transform `year_month` into a dataframe and then perform an inner join on the `year_month` dataframe and your other dataframe.

Comment: Can you tell me expected ouput

Comment: Expected output that I want is :  | id | year | month ||  | 1 | 2020 | 01 |

Comment: Your expected output from the sample data would provide record with `id=3` also. I have updated the answer with some scala code to perform this filter along with expected output and explanations. Please let me know if this works

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by

1. Create a dataframe from `year_month`
2. Perform an inner join on `year_month` with your original dataframe on `month` and `year`
3. Choosing distinct records

The resulting dataframe will be the matched rows

### Working Example

#### Setup

```scala
import spark.implicits._
val dfData =  Seq((1,2020,1),(2,2019,3),(3,2020,1))
val df = dfData.toDF()
               .selectExpr("_1 as id"," _2 as year","_3 as month")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("original_data")

val year_month = Seq((2019,1),(2020,1),(2021,1))
```

#### Step 1

```scala
// Create Temporary DataFrame
val yearMonthDf = year_month.toDF()
                            .selectExpr("_1 as year","_2 as month" )
yearMonthDf.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_year_month")
```

#### Step 2

```scala
var dfResult = spark.sql("select o.id, o.year, o.month from original_data o inner join temp_year_month t on o.year = t.year and o.month = t.month")
```

#### Step3

```scala
var dfResultDistinct = dfResult.distinct()
```

#### Output

```scala
dfResultDistinct.show()
```

```
+---+----+-----+                                                                
| id|year|month|
+---+----+-----+
|  1|2020|    1|
|  3|2020|    1|
+---+----+-----+
```

NB. If you are interested in finding the similar records that exist irrespective of the id. You could update the spark sql to the following (it has removed `o.id`)

```sql
select 
    o.year, 
    o.month 
from 
    original_data o 
inner join 
    temp_year_month t on o.year = t.year and 
                         o.month = t.month
```

which would give as the result

```
+----+-----+                                                                
|year|month|
+----+-----+
|2020|    1|
+----+-----+
```